# Failed RAID 1 drive in a logical volume - lost cause?

Tags: linux, raid, lvm

I have a non-critical CentOS 6.5 server with a rather quirky disk setup:

The main logical volume (mounted as /) comprises two RAID 1 disk pairs, so it's made up from md1 (2TB) and md2 (1.5TB). Recently, one of the drives in md2 failed so, having a spare, I failed it, removed it from the array, replaced it and fired up the server. This caused md2 to turn up as md127, which I corrected by re-assembling the pair as md2, but this resulted in the logical volume deciding it was corrupt and fsck throws up a ton or errors.

I do have a full backup of the data from this server so I can either work out the problem - if quick and simple - or just setup from scratch and restore the data. I get the feeling it would be simpler to start again from scratch  (with a more sensible mount structure).

Any thoughts!?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about `md127`. You will never actually refer to this anyway unless you're doing maintenance on the array, and the system is smart enough to find whatever happens to be on it.

Comment: `md127` occurs when the system automatically find an md device that is not on the expected connector AFAIK. E.g. I once moved my two RAID 1 disks to other connectors; md127 appeared. No problem once one notices. More worrisome is: why would fsck throw up tons of errors? That ain't normal.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer the dynamically generated /dev/md(127-n) names can show up for many reasons.  For example if you use a symbolic `--name` for your array instead of just giving a specific device.  IMO using the symbolic names should be the standard practice.